# File not being saved onClick

Tags: android, file, download

Setting up a download onClick. I don't get any errors...the file just never gets saved. Can anyone tell me what I missed. Pulling my hair out for 2 hours, and it's probably something so small...

Here's the code:

```
        package com.mynavy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.*;

import android.util.*;
import android.os.*;
import java.io.*;

public class YNrank extends Activity {
    Button E4;
    String url1 = "http://doni.daps.dla.mil/SECNAV%20Manuals1/5000.2.pdf";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rank_select);
        addListenerOnButton();      
    }
    public void addListenerOnButton() 

      { 
              E4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.E4);
              E4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 

              {

                public void onClick(View v){
                    new download().execute(url1);

                }

                class download extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{


                    protected String doInBackground(String... url1) {

                    try {

                        URL url = new URL(url1[0]);
                        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                            .openConnection();

                    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/download/E4.pdf";

                    InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(path);
                    int read = 0;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
                    while( (read = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                      output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                        output.close();
                        in.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;

                    }
                }
        });
};}
```

Done some updates to the code. To answer some questions. 
Yes I have INTERNET and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions.
Took out the Toast.

LOGCAT FOR Stack Output:

```
11-03 05:08:13.557: D/dalvikvm(1364): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 154K, 7% free 3682K/3952K, paused 34ms, total 46ms
11-03 05:08:14.196: W/System.err(1364): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/download/E4.pdf: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-03 05:08:14.206: W/System.err(1364):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
11-03 05:08:14.216: W/System.err(1364):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
11-03 05:08:14.226: W/System.err(1364):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
11-03 05:08:14.226: W/System.err(1364):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:117)
11-03 05:08:14.236: W/System.err(1364):     at com.mynavy.YNrank$1$download.doInBackground(YNrank.java:54)
11-03 05:08:14.236: W/System.err(1364):     at com.mynavy.YNrank$1$download.doInBackground(YNrank.java:1)
11-03 05:08:14.256: W/System.err(1364):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-03 05:08:14.256: W/System.err(1364):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-03 05:08:14.266: W/System.err(1364):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-03 05:08:14.266: W/System.err(1364):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-03 05:08:14.278: W/System.err(1364):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-03 05:08:14.278: W/System.err(1364):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-03 05:08:14.286: W/System.err(1364): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-03 05:08:14.296: W/System.err(1364):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
11-03 05:08:14.306: W/System.err(1364):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
11-03 05:08:14.316: W/System.err(1364):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
11-03 05:08:14.316: W/System.err(1364):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Your toast is displayed immediately after you start the asynctask, so it's not really true. You have to put that toast in the onPostExecute method.

Comment: did you give INTERNET permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are retrieving the file from the network, and you are assuming the the whole file is already available.. that could be true, but it could be wrong.

```
int read = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
while( (read = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
  output.write(buffer, 0, read);
}

output.close();
input.close();
```

Also you need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

EDIT

try changing

```
 URL url = new URL(url1[0]);
 URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
 conexion.connect();
 InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
```

with

```
URL url = new URL(url1[0]);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();

InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

and see if it makes any difference.

Also, the UI should be managed only from the UI Thread. Move this row

```
 Toast.makeText(null, "FAIL!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

inside `onPostExecute` or use an `Handler` to post a `Runnable` in the UI Thread queue

Comment: I have the permissions. I added the code you gave but it still wont download.

Comment: Do you have the INTERNET permissimo?

Comment: Yes I did. Still cant find issue

Comment: check logcat for error or exception. You should check also the status code of the http request. Also Editi your question and put the changes you brought to the code

Comment: I edit my question. There is always a logcat output. It could be warning or a debug level. Every piece of information can be useful to track down the problem. You can not say, it does not work, and pretend that people extract from a magic hat the solution for your problem

Comment: I was hoping it was a simple issue with the code I had, since it was late at night I was looking for a proofread. When I pressed the button I never got an output. Now there is one.

Comment: you are getting an exception due of the Toast. Remember that AsynTask is backend by a ExectuorService (Read Thread) != from the UI Thread an d only the UI Thread can touch the UI

Comment: Thought I put that in the wrong place. Took it out for now. Now when I press the button there is literally no LOGCAT output. Just the ones where it tells me how many frames it skipped because my emulator isnt perfect.

Comment: inside the catch block add e.printStackTrace(); and post the logcat output

Comment: Updated. Posted. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: please update also the code, and in YNrank which one is the row 53?

Comment: I think its 
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
Not 100% sure though

Comment: SOrry! Somehow I completely overlooked that jumping down to the comments. One sec!

Comment: Throwing an error in the code.
 The method openConnection() is undefined for the type String

Comment: Update your code and tell me do you get this error. Remember the throw an error is tipically at runtime. is it a runtime error or a compile time error?

Comment: are you sure the file exist? The url is valid? Have you tried with another url? I tried this url www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/intro-linux.pdf‎ and it worked.

Comment: So that URL doesnt work anymore? But I picked a random PDF. Clicked it and now it looks like its telling me the "file" doesnt exist. Its supposed to make that isnt it?

Comment: I put it on my phone and it worked!! Thank you SOOO much for your help. You are amazing!!

Comment: you are welcome. Please read the documentation next time. Mark the answer as accepted